# C# WPF Adding table border programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating a program that takes backup. On the Dashboard I have a table that I have created programmatically. However I want:

1. Border of table to be #cccccc
2. Headcell to have border-top #ffffff
3. Each row to have border-bottom #cccccc

Screenshot of my program:
[image]

Drawing of how I want the table to look:

[image]

My code (https://github.com/europa9/Windows_Backup_Folders_to_External_Disks_Csharp):

```
       /*- Draw log table ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    private void drawLogTable() {


        Table oTable = new Table();


        // Create n columns and add them to the table's Columns collection.
        int numberOfColumns = 3;
        for (int x = 0; x < numberOfColumns; x++){
            oTable.Columns.Add(new TableColumn());
        }

        // Create and add an empty TableRowGroup Rows.
        oTable.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());

        // Add the table head row.
        oTable.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());

        // Configure the table head row
        TableRow currentRow = oTable.RowGroups[0].Rows[0];
        var brushConverter = new BrushConverter();
        currentRow.Background = (Brush)brushConverter.ConvertFrom("#FFe2e2e2"); // grey background
        currentRow.Foreground = (Brush)brushConverter.ConvertFrom("#FF000000"); // black text
        currentRow.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI"); ;
        currentRow.FontSize = 16;
        currentRow.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;


        // Add the header row with content,
        currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Date time"))));
        currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Directory"))));
        currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("File"))));

        // Read file and add rows
        string userPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
        string filePath = userPath + "\\" + "WindowsBackupFoldersToExternalDisk" + "\\" + "config" + "\\" + "log.txt";
        if (File.Exists(filePath)) {

            // Read file
            string existingFolders = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "\n" };
            string[] existsingFoldersArray = existingFolders.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);

            // Loop trough file
            String lastDirectory = "";
            int countLines = 1;

            Brush brushEven = (Brush)brushConverter.ConvertFrom("#FFf3f3f3"); // grey background
            Brush brushOdd = (Brush)brushConverter.ConvertFrom("#FFf8f8f8"); // grey background
            String styleHandler = "even";
            foreach (string line in existsingFoldersArray)
            {
                if (!(line.Equals(""))) {

                    string[] stringLineSeparators = new string[] { "|" };
                    string[] lineArray = line.Split(stringLineSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    String dateTime  = lineArray[0]; // Datetime
                    String directory = lineArray[1]; // Directory
                    String file      = lineArray[2].Replace(directory.ToString(), ""); // File

                    if (lastDirectory.Equals(directory.ToString()))
                    {
                        directory = "";
                    }

                    // Add new row
                    oTable.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
                    currentRow = oTable.RowGroups[0].Rows[countLines];

                    //Configure the row layout
                    if (styleHandler.Equals("odd")){
                        currentRow.Background = brushOdd;
                        styleHandler = "even";
                    }
                    else { 
                        currentRow.Background = brushEven;
                        styleHandler = "odd";
                    }
                    currentRow.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI"); ;
                    currentRow.FontSize = 16;

                    //Add the country name in the first cell
                    currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(dateTime))));
                    currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(directory))));
                    currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(file))));


                    // Last directory
                    lastDirectory = directory;
                    countLines = countLines+1;
                } // not empty
            } //foreach 


        } // file exists


        //Add the given flow document to the window
        FlowDocument flowDocument = new FlowDocument();
        flowDocument.Blocks.Add(oTable);
        contentControlDashboardLog.Content = flowDocument;

    }
```

Comment: What is your question actually? Markup in WPF is usually done using XAML, not the code behind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the properties directly on the `Block` elements:

```
var brushConverter = new BrushConverter();
var tableBorderBrush = brushConverter.ConvertFrom("#CCCCCC");
tableBorderBrush.Freeze();

var headerCellBorderBrush = brushConverter.ConvertFrom("#FFFFFF");
headerCellBorderBrush.Freeze();

private void drawLogTable() 
{
  Table oTable = new Table() { BorderThickness = new Thickness(1), BorderBrush = tableBorderBrush }

  // Add the header row with content,
  currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Date time"))) { BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 1, 0, 0), BorderBrush = headerCellBorderBrush });
  currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("Directory"))) { BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 1, 0, 0), BorderBrush = headerCellBorderBrush });
  currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("File"))) { BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 1, 0, 0), BorderBrush = headerCellBorderBrush });



  // Read file and add rows
  ...
  foreach (string line in existingFoldersArray)
  {
    ...

    // Add new row
    oTable.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
    currentRow = oTable.RowGroups[0].Rows[countLines];
    ...

    //Add the row's cells with their borders set
    currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(dateTime))) { BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 1), BorderBrush = tableBorderBrush });
    currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(directory))) { BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 1), BorderBrush = tableBorderBrush });
    currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(file))) { BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 1), BorderBrush = tableBorderBrush });

    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

The border of a row is the border of the cell. To set the border of a row, the border of each `TableCell` has to be set.

I highly recommend using XAML with `DataTemplates` to accomplish this instead. This is easier, more readable, easier to understand and more flexible. You also have the WYSIWYGn feature of the XAML Designer.

Comment: 'TableRow' does not contain a definition for 'BorderThickness'
&
'TableRow' does not contain a definition for 'BorderBrush'

Comment: @Europa True. You have to set those values on each `TableCell` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at DataTemplates also.